# Datatable inline editing not working as it should

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

I have a datatable script of inline editing, it's working perfect. The trouble is that ajax is not sending data to POST to php. I don't know what to do, because i consider my code is correct. The inline is working, the inputs appear when i press on edit, and when i press save it calls me the test.php but it doesn't post data. Here is my js.

**JS**

```
function editRow(oTable, nRow) {
            var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
            var jqTds = $('>td', nRow);
            jqTds[0].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" id="nume" value="' + aData[0] + '">';
            jqTds[1].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" id="prenume" value="' + aData[1] + '">';
            jqTds[2].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[2] + '">';
            jqTds[3].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[3] + '">';
            jqTds[4].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[4] + '">';
            jqTds[5].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[5] + '">';
            jqTds[6].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[6] + '">';
            jqTds[7].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[7] + '">';
            jqTds[8].innerHTML = '<a class="edit" href="">Save</a> <a class="cancel" href="">Cancel</a>';

        }

        function saveRow(oTable, nRow) {
            var jqInputs = $('input', nRow);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[0].value, nRow, 0, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[1].value, nRow, 1, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[2].value, nRow, 2, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[3].value, nRow, 3, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[4].value, nRow, 4, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[5].value, nRow, 5, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[6].value, nRow, 6, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[7].value, nRow, 7, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate('<a class="edit" href="">Edit</a>', nRow, 8, false);
            oTable.fnDraw();
        }


        table.on('click', '.edit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            /* Get the row as a parent of the link that was clicked on */
            var nRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];

            if (nEditing !== null && nEditing != nRow) {
                /* Currently editing - but not this row - restore the old before continuing to edit mode */
                restoreRow(oTable, nEditing);
                editRow(oTable, nRow);
                nEditing = nRow;
            } else if (nEditing == nRow && this.innerHTML == "Save") {
                /* Editing this row and want to save it */
                saveRow(oTable, nEditing);
                nEditing = null;
                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'test.php',
                data: {num: $('#nume').val()},
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $("#content").html(data);
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
            } else {
                /* No edit in progress - let's start one */
                editRow(oTable, nRow);
                nEditing = nRow;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Inspect element to see what structure actually made after rendering with datatables... also this is not a genral issue try to make a feedle to get better help.

Comment: the structure is good, here is the html generated after i press edit`<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" id="nume" value="">`

Answer (score 0):

Try this before the ajax call and it should work.

```
var data = {};
                $.each(jqInputs, function( index, val ) {
                  // data.push(val.value);
                  data[val.id] = val.value;
                });
                // console.log(data);
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'controller/ajax/bars/update_bar_timing',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {'jqInputs':data},
                    success: function(result){
                    }
                });
```